# Connecting to the database using Visual-Paradigm

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, information-schema, visual-paradigm

I just have started using Visual Paradigm and I am trying to connect to my database which is used by Iphone App. It sits in one of my folders(named Project.db). I would like to connect to  it and facing some problems in doing so.

Steps I followed:

```
1) Click Tools -> Database -> Reverse Database
2) A pop up opens up, Language is Java and click next
3) Driver is sqlite and using JDBC to connect to the database, so I am using sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2-sources.jar that I downloaded.( Not really sure abt this)
4) Under the connection url: selected the jdbc:sqlite:Project.db option.( Am i doing this right?)

But when I click Test Connection, it says connect successful.
```

However, when I click next, no table are shown. What am i doing wrong? Need some guidance and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing may cause this problem happen is leaving database name empty. Have you Entered your database name?